# PhoneGap Build won't build for Android with PushPlugin

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, visual-studio-2015, phonegap-pushplugin

We have a PhoneGap app which refuses to build once we add in `PushPlugin`.

Specifically when using PhoneGap Build we get the error:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:573: ../../../../../../home/ec2-user/android-sdk/com.android.support:support-v4:+ resolve to a path with no project.properties file for project /project
```

We can occasionally get it to build using the Ripple emulator (building in Visual Studio) after updating PhoneGap (`$ npm update -g phonegap`) and the PhoneGap Android Platform (`$ phonegap platform update android`) to the latest versions.

We have included the plugin like this:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" />
```

Or, when building in Visual Studio 2015:

```
<vs:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin" version="2.5.0" src="https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps" />
```

Can anyone suggest where we might be going wrong?

**EDIT:**

We’ve also tried building on the command line, but even after installing `cordova-plugin-android-support-v4`, thus;

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-android-support-v4
    Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-android-support-v4" via npm
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-plugin-android-support-v4
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-plugin-android-support-v4
    Installing "cordova-plugin-android-support-v4" for android
```

we still get errors:

```
C:\Dev\CordovaBlank\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1>cordova build android
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Dev\CordovaBlank\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat""
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\java\jdk1.7.0_55
Running: C:\Dev\CordovaBlank\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Dev\CordovaBlank\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordova
dle.daemon=true

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
  > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v4:+.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.897 secs

C:\Dev\CordovaBlank\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "C:\Dev\CordovaBlank\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Dev\Cor
latforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:134:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NEW Push Plugin released recently. 
Read this (via the Offical Blog), and get the details:
http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2015/07/phonegap-plugin-push-version-111.html

**UPDATE (2015-10-24):** According to the Phonegap Build blog of Sept 28, 2015
[Android Builds Now Using Gradle By Default](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/09/28/android-using-gradle/).

`Ant` is still available, and can be force into use - with
 `<preference name="android-build-tool" value="ant" />`

Other related changes occur, including *automatic minSdkVersion versioning* and *validation of 9-patch images*. Read the blog post for details.

**NOTE:** <s>On your original problem, gradle (not officially supported by phonegap) is the problem. Some people have worked around this problem, by forcing `ant` to run in it's place. To find those other posts, search back 30 days from this post; the subjects are similar to this and included: "Failed to build".</s>

Answer (score 4):

For PhoneGap Build, use 
`<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" version="2.4.0" />` to force it to use the older, supported, version.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the plugin and install it via command line using this command:

```
cordova plugin add com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin --save
```

You will notice the plugin will show in your config.xml like this:

```
<plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin" spec="^2.2.1" />
```

but it won't show on the config designer, for that to happen, add "vs:" in front of the plugin tag:

```
<vs:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin" spec="^2.2.1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not 100% work, but work for me).

remove this line in platforms/android/project.properties

> cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:+

if you are using facebook plugin (like me), you can ignore below.

> cordova plugin add android.support.v4